# Htaccess with ip list ban/redirect

Tags: .htaccess, ddos

I'm having trouble with Chinese bots, they're performing DDoS attacks.

As a precaution, I'm thinking about doing routing with Htaccess. I want to forward requests from abroad to a specific php page.

```
In htaccess

> <Limit GET HEAD POST>
>     order deny,allow
>     allow from 2.16.88.0/24
>     allow from 2.56.60.0/22
>     allow from 2.56.152.0/22
>     allow from 2.57.188.0/22
>     allow from 2.58.40.0/22
>     allow from 2.58.68.0/22
>     allow from 2.58.124.0/22
>     allow from 2.58.140.0/22
>     allow from 2.59.116.0/24
>     ....
>     deny from all </Limit>
```

Comment: And what's your question? How is this related to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ErrorDocument 403 ctrl.php` to the first line of your .HTACCESS document, any denied requests will be served this file.

Completed .htaccess file should look like the following:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /botctrl.php
Order Allow, Deny
Allow from 2.16.88.0/24
Allow from 2.56.60.0/22
Allow from 2.56.152.0/22
Allow from 2.57.188.0/22
Allow from 2.58.40.0/22
Allow from 2.58.68.0/22
Allow from 2.58.124.0/22
Allow from 2.58.140.0/22
Allow from 2.59.116.0/24
Deny from All
```

If this is becoming a problem from a DDoS-ing stand point, you might want to look into Fail2Ban or CloudFlare DDoS mitigation to better protect your systems as this .htaccess fix will only redirect HTTP request and not ping attacks or other port attacks.

Comment: should it be  ErrorDocument 403 /ctrl.php

Comment: Use the absolute path of the file relative to the web directory, so if you 'ctrl.php' file is in your main folder, then '/ctrl.php' would be correct, yes. You can also give an external URL like 'https://www.google.com' as well. Hope this helps

Comment: help me  please please

Comment: ErrorDocument 403 /botctrl.php 
this did not happen

Comment: @ZaferKırık using the following in your htaccess should work.
ErrorDocument 403 /ctrl.php
Order Allow, Deny
Allow from 2.16.88.0/24
Allow from 2.56.60.0/22
Allow from 2.56.152.0/22
Allow from 2.57.188.0/22
Allow from 2.58.40.0/22
Allow from 2.58.68.0/22
Allow from 2.58.124.0/22
Allow from 2.58.140.0/22
Allow from 2.59.116.0/24
Deny from All

Comment: @ZaferKırık see modified answer for full .htaccess layout

Comment: no just added nothing changed  apache module may be missing